# How do I get the matched part of a wildcard in a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a(.*)b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("a19203b");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

This prints out the entire string (`a19203b`). All I need is `19203`. How can I get this in Java?

(for example, in a mod_rewrite rule, I would do something like `RewriteRule article/(.*) article.php?id=$1` where `$1` is the string I need)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. Instead of `matcher.group()`, use `matcher.group(1)`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a(.*)b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("a19203b");
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: True, but don't call `find()` just for its side-effect like that.  You should always call it within a `if` or `while` statement, so you know whether the match actually succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookbehinds/lookaheads :

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=a).*(?=b)");
```

Don't capture what you don't want to capture. Here your entire match will be what you want.